# detect from which recognizer a gesture is coming

Tags: ios, tags, uigesturerecognizer

I have 2 views: view with tag 1 and view with tag 2.
Each view has two gesture recognizers.

```
CGRect tempRect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);


for (int i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tempRect];
    UIImageView *tempImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:tempRect];
    tempImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@",@"image_",i,@".png"]];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *tempRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [tempRecognizer performSelector:@selector(SwipeRight:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    [tempRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [tempView addGestureRecognizer:tempRecognizer];
    [tempView addSubview:tempImageView];
    tempView.tag=i;
    [self.view addSubview:tempView];
}
```

I have a method: SwipeRight that manages the swipe....

```
-(void)SwipeRight:(NSNumber*)MyTag{

    int MyProgr = [MyTag intValue];

    }
```

Which is the correct way to pass the tag?
With my code I got an error:

`[UISwipeGestureRecognizer SwipeRight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set the View Tag before**

```
[tempView setTag:i];
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callYourMethod:)];
            swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
            [tempView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];


- (void)callYourMethod:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        int tagValue = recognizer.view.tag;
        NSLog(@"Down");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one

```
-(void) SwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
     if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
     {
           int tag = recognizer.view.tag;
     }
}
```